# How to call SetInformationJobObject with just JOB_OBJECT_BASIC_LIMIT_INFORMATION?

Tags: delphi, winapi, delphi-2010

I have a basic translation of the Job API, which is as follows:

```
type
  TJobObjectInfoClass = (
    JobObjectBasicLimitInformation = 2,
    JobObjectExtendedLimitInformation = 9
  );

  TJobObjectBasicLimitInformation = record
    PerProcessUserTimeLimit: TLargeInteger;
    PerJobUserTimeLimit: TLargeInteger;
    LimitFlags: DWORD;
    MinimumWorkingSetSize: DWORD;
    MaximumWorkingSetSize: DWORD;
    ActiveProcessLimit: DWORD;
    Affinity: DWORD;
    PriorityClass: DWORD;
    SchedulingClass: DWORD;
  end;

  TIOCounters = record
    ReadOperationCount: UInt64;
    WriteOperationCount: UInt64;
    OtherOperationCount: UInt64;
    ReadTransferCount: UInt64;
    WriteTransferCount: UInt64;
    OtherTransferCount: UInt64;
  end;

  TJobObjectExtendedLimitInformation = record
    BasicLimitInformation: TJobObjectBasicLimitInformation;
    IoInfo: TIOCounters;
    ProcessMemoryLimit: DWORD;
    JobMemoryLimit: DWORD;
    PeakProcessMemoryUsed: DWORD;
    PeakJobMemoryUsed: DWORD;
  end;

const
  CREATE_BREAKAWAY_FROM_JOB = $01000000;
  JOB_OBJECT_LIMIT_KILL_ON_JOB_CLOSE = $00002000;

function AssignProcessToJobObject(const hJob, hProcess: THandle): BOOL; stdcall;
external kernel32 name 'AssignProcessToJobObject';

function CreateJobObject(const lpJobAttributes: PSecurityAttributes;
  const lpName: PChar): THandle; stdcall;
external kernel32 name {$IFDEF UNICODE}'CreateJobObjectW'{$ELSE}'CreateJobObjectA'{$ENDIF};

function SetInformationJobObject(const hJob: THandle;
  const JobObjectInformationClass: TJobObjectInfoClass;
  const lpJobObjectInformation: Pointer;
  const cbJobObjectInformationLength: DWORD): BOOL; stdcall;
external kernel32 name 'SetInformationJobObject';
```

When I use it as follows, it works fine:

```
Job := CreateJobObject(nil, nil);
if Job = 0 then
  RaiseLastOSError;

ZeroMemory(@JELI, SizeOf(JELI));
JELI.BasicLimitInformation.LimitFlags := JOB_OBJECT_LIMIT_KILL_ON_JOB_CLOSE;
Win32Check(SetInformationJobObject(
  Job, JobObjectExtendedLimitInformation, @JELI, SizeOf(JELI))
);
```

Since I'm only setting the `BasicLimitInformation`, I expected to be able to instead call `SetInformationJobObject` with just that:

```
ZeroMemory(@JBLI, SizeOf(JBLI));
JBLI.LimitFlags := JOB_OBJECT_LIMIT_KILL_ON_JOB_CLOSE;
Win32Check(SetInformationJobObject(
  Job, JobObjectBasicLimitInformation, @JBLI, SizeOf(JBLI))
);
```

The docs on MSDN don't give me any indication that this is not supported. Why is it then that it fails with code 87 ("The parameter is incorrect")?

My best guess would be that my record does not exactly match the struct that Windows expects, meaning some of the bits are in the wrong place. Yet, when it is embedded in another one, it works fine. In there, it is the first field, so that makes it unlikely that padding is the cause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation for [`JOB_OBJECT_BASIC_LIMIT_INFORMATION`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684147%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> [`JOB_OBJECT_LIMIT_KILL_ON_JOB_CLOSE`] requires use of a `JOBOBJECT_EXTENDED_LIMIT_INFORMATION` structure. Its `BasicLimitInformation` member is a `JOBOBJECT_BASIC_LIMIT_INFORMATION` structure."

The `extended` struct starts out with a `basic` struct, so the two structures are at least partially compatible, which is why you don't get random results.

This should give the correct result:

```
ZeroMemory(@JELI, SizeOf(JELI));
JELI.BasicLimitInformation.LimitFlags := JOB_OBJECT_LIMIT_KILL_ON_JOB_CLOSE;
Win32Check(SetInformationJobObject(
  Job, JobObjectBasicLimitInformation, @JELI, SizeOf(JELI))
);
```